# MySQL find top x% across a given time period

Tags: php, mysql, sql, percentile

I fear this could get quite complicated quite quickly, but I'm wondering what the best method is of showing the latest 'activity' ordered by 'popularity' - which is measures in either 'likes' or 'views' (even perhaps both, if possible - counting likes as 2x views?).

So if I have a database full of posts with views and/or likes, I want to be able to show the top 5% most popular, posts within the last 24 hours.

I have 3 tables for this, one for posts and two for the likes and views (1 row = 1 like / view)

table 1 = "posts"

```
id | title | timestamp | etc.
```

table 2 = "posts_likes"

```
post_id | user_id
```

table 3 = "posts_views"

```
post_id | user_id
```

Using MySQL + PHP, what would be the best way of running this query to order my posts by their overall, calulated popularity?

Many thanks, Tim

Comment: the best start, at least, would be to show your tables structure.

Comment: And to show what you have tried.

Comment: Tim, we expect to see the table structure and what have you tried by now...

Comment: I've added table structure, I've tried a few methods @daniel, but I'm struggling..

Comment: Tim, also, dont add a signature to your post. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: @Tim: Be concrete: What have you tried and what are the problems with your approaches? Like this, people can more easily help you, because they can just fix your approach instead having to come up with it from the beginning.

Comment: It's impossible with the structure you've provided since it doesn't contain any indication of when the data was created.

Comment: `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 0, XXX`, coming this XXX from a calculation.

Comment: What is the problem? Calculating the number of posts for the 5% percentage? Applying a variable limit? All of them?

Comment: I've updated my post, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Tim, you also need timestamp in the likes and views tables. I'm formulating a idea and I will post it to you in a few minutes.

Comment: 3 great answers, shame that I can only choose one...

Comment: @Tim I think pedromarce answer is the right way to solve your specfic problem. My post is more about ways to formulate a ranking algorithm. Can you please give it to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some pseudo sql just to show the idea I would use, you can add the missing bits and get it working. 
It assumes that the top 5% is based in the number of posts, but if it was based in the score of likes plus views, should be trivial to adjust.

```
SET @foo=0.05 * select count(*) from posts where (timestamp < today - 24 hours); 
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT posts,sum(likes) * 2 + sum(views) as POPULAR FROM (tables joined) ORDER BY popular LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @foo;
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, as I don't have a MySQL server accessible right now - but the below query should get you started:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, ((COUNT(l.id) * 2) + COUNT(v.id)) AS popularity 
    FROM posts p 
        LEFT JOIN posts_likes l ON l.post_id = p.id 
        LEFT JOIN posts_views v ON v.post_id = p.id 
    WHERE p.timestamp > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400)
    GROUP BY p.id
    ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT :return_limit
```

When you run the query, you'll need to pass a parameter `:return_limit` - Which should be 5% of the `COUNT()` of all posts in the past 24 hours.

Comment: I don't think hammering it to 24 hours is a good idea. A post can be popular for a very long time.

Comment: But the requirements said : " I want to be able to show the top 5% most popular, posts within the last 24 hours.", so very popular old posts are irrelevant...